# Javascript Regex test same string but got different result

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a weird situation. I am using a Regex testing some strings. I would like to seal them to a class, like the following:

```
export class RegexPattern {
  static price = (/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/g);
  static phone = (/^([0-9]{0,5}-)?[0-9]{10}$/g);
}
```

So lets say the input is `'32'`

But when I use it to test same strings twice, the first time will pass, the second time will fail, eg:

```
RegexPattern.price.test('32')  //return ture
RegexPattern.price.test('32')  // return false
```

But if I use it with bare Regex, without sealing:

```
(/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/g).test('32')  //return ture
(/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/g).test('32')  // return true
```

My question is why did this happen?

Comment: maybe you need to instantiate the class first like const regexPattern = new RegexPattern()

Comment: @Joven28 I don't think it needs initiate the class. And also I tried that, it will return undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RegExp` object keeps track of the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) where a match occurred, so on subsequent matches it will start from the last used index, instead of 0.

If you don't want to manually reset `lastIndex` to 0 after every test, just remove the `g` flag.

When you test the regex individually, you're actually creating a new regexp object with every invocation, that's why that works. If you were doing:

```
'use strict';

const regex = /^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/g;

console.log(regex.test(32));
console.log(regex.test(32));
```

You would get `true`, `false`, too.